# how to use global variable in twig if statment?

Tags: php, twig

I assigned a new global variable in twig :

```
 $twig->addGlobal("lang", Config::$lang);
```

and I want to check this variable in if statement but it doesn't work

```
   {% if lang == 'en' %}
```

how to check global variable in if statement?

Comment: "it doesnt work" is not an error. what error or exception are you getting?

Comment: I don't get an error.when `lang` variable equal to `en` if statement return false.why?

Comment: try to print `{{ lang }}` . Are you getting any output ?

Comment: @Rikesh : yes, out put is `en`

Comment: @Mr-Moqadam - Great !! Than just use it that way in your condition I hope it will work there too.

Comment: @Rikesh : i said it doesn't work when I use in if statement.

Comment: Use like that means  `{% if {{ lang }} ..`

Comment: @Rikesh : I get an error !!!